# element id get value for data attribute

Tags: javascript

After running this script #result will hold some value (for example 85). I need to put this value (85) into the `data-price` attribute.

How to do that?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#calc-dist').onclick = function() {
            const lat1 = document.querySelector('#lat1').value;
            const lon1 = document.querySelector('#lon1').value;
            const lat2 = document.querySelector('#lat2').value;
            const lon2 = document.querySelector('#lon2').value;
            const p1 = new LatLon(Dms.parseDMS(lat1), Dms.parseDMS(lon1));
            const p2 = new LatLon(Dms.parseDMS(lat2), Dms.parseDMS(lon2));
            const dist = parseFloat(p1.distanceTo(p2).toPrecision(4));
            document.querySelector('#result').textContent = dist;
    }
});

<span data-price=" " id="result"></span>
```

Comment: This code is hard to understand and seems incomplete

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('#result').setAttribute('data-price', dist);`

Comment: just tested now not working, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the data attribute:

```
document.querySelector('#result').setAttribute('data-price', 85);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Sorry misread the question as getting the data-price attribute at first - hence the edits

You can also use the dataset property:

```
document.querySelector('#result').dataset.price = 85
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

If using dataset check if you need older browser support:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset